# how to pass a pandas dataframe to html

Tags: python, html, pandas, frontend

I've a sample dataframe

```
city          city_website
LosAngeles     https://la.com
Ohio           https://ohio.com
Buffalo        https://buffalo.com
Manhattan      https://manhattan.com
```

How can I pass the dataframe to my sample template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="CITIES URLs">CITIES NAMES</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately my html template doesn't accept a direct dataframe to display the content. I'm tring to pass the dataframe as string to my html `df = df.to_string()`. But resulting in

```html
<html>
<body>
<p>Losangeles https://la.com Ohio https://ohio.com Buffalo https://buffalo.com Manhattan https://manhattan.com</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Looking for the desired result

```html
<html>
<body>
<a href='https://la.com'>LA</a>
<br><a href='https://ohio.com'>Ohio</a>
<br><a href='https://buffalo.com'>Buffalo</a>
<br><a href='https://manhattan.com'>Manhattan</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `df.to_html()` to get an html table

Comment: It doesnt give me the hyperlink tags right?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get the `render_links` argument to work properly, you can generate the html string and pass it to your template

```
def city_link(row):
    return f"<a href='{row.city_website}'>{row.city}</a>"

city_links = df.apply(city_link, axis=1)
html = '<br>'.join(city_links.values)
```